# Lightning button no action and not clickable

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, lightning, developer

In my Case detail page there is a button Reopen Case, but the button is visible only when case status is completed.
Currently I'm working on a case which has the status Completed, Now Reopen case button is coming up, but when I'm trying to click that button, there is no action in itemizedlist even though cursor also no action button is not clickable. By clicking that button I'm trying to open a modal window. But the button is no action ,
even through not clickable also. kindly help me out to find the issue on below code.

```html
<template>
    <template if:true={showReopenBtn}>
        <div class="slds-media__body ">
            <lightning-button variant="brand" class="slds-float_right" label="Reopen Case" onclick={handleReopen}>                
            </lightning-button>
        </div>
    </template>
    <lightning-record-edit-form record-id={recordId} object-api-name="Case"
            onsuccess={handleSuccess} onsubmit ={handleSubmit} onload={handleOnLoad} data-id="caseForm"
            onerror={handleError}>
            
<!-- modal start -->      
   <template if:true={isShowReopenModal}>
        <section role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modal-heading-01" aria-modal="true" aria-describedby="modal-content-id-1" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open">
        <div class="slds-modal__container">
        <!-- modal header start -->
        <header class="slds-modal__header">
            <button class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-modal__close slds-button_icon-inverse" title="Close" onclick={hideModalBox}>
                <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:close"
                alternative-text="close"
                variant="inverse"
                size="small" ></lightning-icon>
                <span class="slds-assistive-text">Close</span>
            </button>
            <h2 id="modal-heading-01" class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-hyphenate">Reopen Case Comment</h2>
        </header>

        <!-- modal body start -->
        <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium">
            <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters"> 

                <lightning-textarea class="slds-m-left_large slds-m-top_medium slds-m-right_large slds-m-bottom_medium"
                    type="text" 
                    value={reopenComment}
                    required="true"
                    variant="label-hidden">
                </lightning-textarea>
                
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- modal footer start-->
        <footer class="slds-modal__footer">
            <lightning-button class="slds-float_left" label="Save" onclick={reopenCaseRequest}></lightning-button>
            <lightning-button class="slds-float_right" label="Cancel" onclick={hideModalBox}>Cancel</lightning-button>
        </footer>

        </div>
        </section>
        <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open"></div>
    </template>
<!-- modal end -->
    <br/><br/><br/><br/>
</template>
```

```javascript
import { LightningElement,api, track,wire } from 'lwc';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import { getRelatedListRecords } from 'lightning/uiRelatedListApi';
import {CurrentPageReference} from 'lightning/navigation';
import { RefreshEvent } from "lightning/refresh";
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';
import UserNameFIELD from '@salesforce/schema/User.Name';
import Id from '@salesforce/user/Id';
import setReopenCaseRequest from '@salesforce/apex/ET_CreateCaseComments.createCaseComm';
import changeOwnerCase from '@salesforce/apex/CaseCreationsController.changeOwnerCase';
import { getRecord, getFieldValue }  from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';

export default class Et_rtQueriesAdhocRequest extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    @track name;
    activeSections = ['Req Info','Deal Info'];
    @track reopenComment = '';
    @track showReopenBtn = false;
    @track isShowReopenModal= false;
    @track showPopup = false;
    @api isLoaded = false;
    
        handleOnLoad(event) {
            this.isLoaded = !this.isLoaded;
            this.showMsg = false;
            console.log('recordId---', this.recordId);
            var record = event.detail.records;
            console.log('record---', record);
            if(record[this.recordId].fields.ET_Instruction__c != null){
                var instruction = record[this.recordId].fields.ET_Instruction__c.value;
            }
            if(record[this.recordId].fields.ET_Change_to_RCF__c != null){
                var changeToRCF = record[this.recordId].fields.ET_Change_to_RCF__c.value;
            }
            var statusValue = record[this.recordId].fields.Status.value;
        }
    
    if(statusValue === 'Completed'){
            this.showReopenBtn = true;
        } else {
            this.showReopenBtn = false;
    }
    
    handleReopen(event) {
        this.isShowReopenModal = true;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you using VF Page as Case Record Detail Page??